# SQlite FTS compress size of "text" number column

Tags: android, sqlite, full-text-search, tokenize

I have an FTS 3 table on an android device.  One of the columns in the table holds arrays of 32-bit numbers in text format.  I'm using FTS because FTS is comparatively extremely fast for finding non unique values given its index system.

The only downside is that a 32 bit number can take 10-11 ascII characters to put into the table (e.g. 1234567890).  That makes a 4 byte number esentially 10-11 bytes of ascII, essentially increasing the size to 250% of original, not to mention the same values also gets shoved in an index, for what I estimated to be a 500% increase.

I figured I could compress the number by turning it into a unique combination of alphanumeric characters.

E.g.

- the simple tokenizer recognizes 26 letters (a-Z), converting uppercase to lowercase.
- it also recognizes 10 numbers (0-9)

that gives me to start 36 combinations per byte to work with.

Which means I could compress up to a 36^6 = 2.17 billion range with 6 characters (just enough to compress the positive range of a 32 bit integer).  Or the entire range (positive and negative) with 7 characters.  A 30% reduction.

But the simple tokenizer also recognizes unicode characters with codepoints >= 128.
Which means, I could skip alphanumeric characters, in favor of unicode characters for compression.

Assuming the toekenizer recognized every code point above 128, one could encode 99.6% of the 32 bit integer range in 4 bytes, and the full range in 5 e.g. (2 unicode16 bit characters + 1 8 bit alphanumeric).

But there lies my question... Much of the unicode ranges are filled with reserved values.  Will the simple tokenizer search on the entire possible code point range (i.e. will reserved values work?), or will it just work for some values (which?).

Answer (score 1):

SQLite does not really care which characters are valid or not (as long as you avoid the surrogate range), but using Unicode characters will not improve storage efficiency by much because in UTF-8, non-ASCII characters can be stored in more than two bytes.

FTS indexes do not store every column value but just word numbers, so they are more efficient when there are duplicates.

If at all possible, you should organize your table so that numbers can be stored as single values in a column.

Comment: You're right, it won't be much of a storage gain.  I failed to account for the fact 5 bits in UTF-16 are signalling bits, just to say "hey i'm a UTF-16 character".   Which means only 11 bits remain to encode numbers.  So instead of 16^2, we have 11^2 which means at least 3 UTF-16 characters (6 bytes) would be needed, assuming every enumerable codepont was valid.  Which is only a 1 byte improvement over what I can do with regular alphanumeric encoding to get the entire int32 range.

Comment: SQLite always used UTF-8, which uses a variable encoding. Characters between U+0080 and U+07FF encode 11 bits in two bytes, between U+0800 and U+FFFF encode 16 bits in three bytes, between U+10000 and U+10FFFF encode 21 bits in four bytes.